# OneToManyRelationship in a django model

Tags: python, django

Let's suppose a city has multiple companies.

```
 city1:{
  company1: [phone1, email1]
  company2: [phone1, email2, phone3]
  }
```

Each company can have one or more phone, email.

I want to store company info as

```
  < city1, company1:[phone1, email1] >
  < city1, company2:[phone1, email2, phone3] >
```

I tried

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)


class CompanyDetails(models.Model):
    com_name = models.ForeignKey(City)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

Because a company can have more than one phone or email, how can I define this?
Any suggestions.

Comment: This isn't many-to-many; an email or phone can only belong to one company, surely. So it's a one-to-many, ie a ForeignKey from Details to Company.

Comment: what database do you use?

Comment: postgreSql.

A company can have multiple phone & email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the question is how to model this properly.

This is in fact not a many-to-many relation. This is a one-to-many relation: one city can have zero or more companies, and a company can have zero or more emails and telephone numbers.

## Approach one: two one-to-many relations

We can model this with four entities `City`, `Company`, `CompanyEmail`, and `CompanyPhone`. Something that looks like this:

```
+------+ 1     N +---------+ 1     N +--------------+
| City |---------| Company |---------| CompanyEmail |
+------+         +---------+    |    +--------------+
| name |         | name    |    |    | email        |
+------+         +---------+    |    +--------------+
                                |
                                |  N +--------------+
                                 \---| CompanyPhone |
                                     +--------------+
                                     | phone        |
                                     +--------------+
```

We can define this as:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

class CompanyEmail(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class CompanyPhone(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

A problem with this modeling however is that the number of relations can become quite large if companies have email addresses, phone numbers, addresses, registration numbers, trademarks, etc. As a result the number of models blow up enourmously.

The advantage however is that we can let the models perform there own checks: a `CompanyEmail` can verify that it is a valid email address, and provide some convenient methods (for example to easily contact the company). If however the number of options is large, then it we have to write some subtantial amount of code.

### Pulling up the company connection

We can ease this a bit, by pulling up the relation to the company in an abstract model (for example `CompanyAttribute`):

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

class CompanyAttribute(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class CompanyEmail(CompanyAttribute):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class CompanyPhone(CompanyAttribute):
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

This does not change anything at the database level, and we still thus defined two one-to-many relations, but here we can encapsulate some logic of a company attribute at the `CompanyAttribute` level.

## Approach two: using an *entity-attribute-value* table

In case the type of attributes can be dynamic (for example a user can introduce a new type of attribute), then we might introduce a *entity-attribute-value* model. We here define four models: `City`, `Company`, `CompanyAttribute`, and `AttributeKind`.

```
+------+ 1    N +---------+ 1    N +------------------+ N    1 +---------------+
| City |--------| Company |--------| CompanyAttribute |--------| AttributeKind |
+------+        +---------+        +------------------+        +---------------+
| name |        | name    |        | value            |        | attributename |
+------+        +---------+        +------------------+        +---------------+
```

Or in Django, this could look like:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

class AttributeKind(models.Model):
    attributename = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class CompanyAttribute(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    kind = models.ForeignKey(AttributeKind)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

We thus can then add two `AttributeKind`s by default: a `phone` and `email`, but we can later decide to add more kinds (address, VAT number, etc.).

We can now dynamically construct new kinds of attributes. A potential problem with this approach however is that it is harder to validate that the content actually makes sense. For example a user can store any string as an email address, it is harder to enforce an actual email address.

Answer (score 4):

In the exact same way as a `City` can have multiple `CompanyDetails`es: by putting them in a separate table.

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)


class CompanyDetails(models.Model):
    com_name = models.ForeignKey(City)


class CompanyEmail(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyDetails)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


# And similar for phone numbers
```

Alternatively, if you are using PostgreSQL only, take a look at [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/).

Comment: can we minimize no. of models, instead of defining four models?

Comment: @Prashant: I don't really see why you want to minimize the number of models. Typically it is better to store separate real entities in separate models, and furthermore it makes it easier to search, update, query, etc.

Comment: I just wanted to check , is it possible?

Comment: Prashant: well you can encode an entire city, even your entire database in a JSON blob, but that would make it ugly, and unscalable.